# SQLite given a statement it is possible to know what table will be touched

Tags: sql, sqlite

given a simple query such as

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO number VALUES (1, 2);
```

I am wondering if it is possible to know, before to execute the query and without parsing the statement myself, that the table `test` is read on the first query and that the table `number` is written in the second query.

This two examples are clearly extremely simple, however I am looking for something that works on more complex cases.

Cheers

Comment: If you are really looking for a parser, then you absolutely need to give us the context of where these queries are located.  Are they in standalone `.sql` files?  Are they buried in application code somewhere, or something else?

Comment: The queries comes in over the networks and they are saved in a char array, then the queries are parsed and executed against the SQLite database.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is too broad.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I simply asked if it is possible to know from SQLite what table will be touched in executing a statement, how it this broad?